# Calling method from inside POST in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have my main.py looking like this:-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util

# imports for sending mail
from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.api import users

message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="Support <xyz@gmail.com>", subject="Email from")

message.to = "info <info@xyz.com>"
message.html = """
<html><head></head><body>
Dear <b>I</b>nfo: <br /><br />
message.<br /><br />

Please let us know if you have any questions.<br /><br />

The flxlmonline.com Support Team
</body></html>
"""


class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("""
          <html>
            <body>
              <form action="/sign" method="post">
              <p>
                <label for="name">Name</label> <input type="text" name="name">
              </p>
              <p>
                <label for="email">E-mail</label> <input type="email" name="email">
              </p>
              <p>
                <label for="message">Message</label> <textarea name="message"></textarea>
              </p>
                <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
              </form>
            </body>
          </html>""")

    def post(self):
    self.response.out.write('<html><body>You wrote:<pre>')
        self.response.out.write(cgi.escape(self.request.get('message')))
        self.response.out.write('</pre></body></html>')
    **sendMail(self.request)**

    def sendMail(request):
        message.send()


application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/', MainHandler),
                                      ('/sign', MainHandler)],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see, I am trying to call another class method called sendEmail() from inside post.  This gives compilation error.  Any idea where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance,
[BTR Naidu](http://www.btrnaidu.com)

Comment: Shouldn't you do self.sendMail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried with?:

```
def post(self):
    # ----
    self.sendMail(self.request)

def sendMail(self, request):
    message.send()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're treating a class method like a function. Choose one:

```
def sendMail(request):
    message.send()

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        sendMail(self.request)
```

Or:

```
class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def sendMail(self):
        # request = self.request
        message.send()

    def post(self):
        self.sendMail()
```